# Appengine Google Cloud Custom Domain. Cannot Include Certificate, Cannot Remove Domain. Why?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, dns, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to include my new ssl certificate in google cloud manager, appengine section, custom domains screen (see links 1 and 2 below). But it have a series of locks that do not allow me to proceed.

First of all, it does not allow me to exclude my old certificate expired yesterday (11-jan-2017), because it is attached to 2 domains (www.horariofacil.com and (naked) horariofacil.com), so that I tried to remove those domains, but it only allows me to remove the www version, not the naked one, as the image attached shows.

Second, I tried to simply include my new certificate, and it does not allow me because of it says that I have not confirmed the ownership of the domains that the new certificate points to, but the new certificate points to the same domains that is already included. So that how can that be possible? I am the ownership of the domain and administrator (full control) of google cloud manager.

Why can not I remove those domains or include new certificate??? Does anyone have a hint here or it is just a bug???

I also make some tests with those other domains that are included. They are no longer used and I tried to remove them directly on DNS manager. They were NOT removed. Google cloud does not update the information. It is impossible to remove. Terrible!

Hope someone can help!

SSL Certificates Screen:

[image]

Custom Domains Screen:

[image]

Comment: In the SSL Certificates Screen click on `my-cert-concat`, it'll open a new screen with checkmarks on each custom domain it is applied to.

Comment: Yes, but it is already unmarked. And by the way, only one option appears here, the www domain. The naked one do not. Check the picture in this link: <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byd_UzOVnR84OWJsX3dsWGgzZGM/view?usp=sharing>

Answer (score 0):

To have this feature enabled you must be domain's owner, i.e. have your domain verified by Google with your account via Google Webmaster Tools.